# Python autocompletion in neovim using deoplete

Tags: autocomplete, neovim

I am trying to set up deoplete in neovim for autocompletion in python. In the screen shot below, you can see that it recognizes numpy module, but when I add "." following "np", I get no autocomplete suggestions at all. How do I debug it?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait a second for autosuggestion to pop up.

Also you can try typing some letters to narrow it down.

[image]